# CocoaPod with debug only dependency fails on xcodebuild

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I am working on a private iOS Swift CocoaPod which is supposed to be used for `DEBUG` builds only. It uses one other CocoaPod as a dependency, which should also be included for `DEBUG` only. All code in the source files that use this dependency are inside the `if #DEBUG` swift flag, To achieve this I added it to my PodSpec with the following line:

```
s.dependency 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift', '~> 9.0', :configurations => :debug
```

However when I run `pod lib lint` it fails on `` Building with `xcodebuild`. `` step, when I run the lint with `--verbose` argument I get the following result:

```
    ld: framework not found OHHTTPStubs
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    
    warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dvhxmheoxqefvffloemufugtmpli/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/<cocoapod_name>/<cocoapod_name>.framework/<cocoapod_name> normal
    (1 failure)
```

When I don't include `, :configurations => :debug` argument everything works as expected, however when I then add my CocoaPod to my iOS project, this will include the `OHHTTPStubs` framework in release builds, even when I add my CocoaPod with the `, :configurations => :debug` argument in the `Podfile` of my iOS project.